# Display multiple Oracle SQL query results on AngularJS page

Tags: sql, angularjs, oracle, html

So I need to display multiple results of SQL query on the same component in AngularJS.

How would I do this? So far, I understood that component can treat only one http request as in here:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('cryostat', []).component('cryostat', {
    templateUrl: 'cryostat/cryostat.template.html',
    controller: function cryostatController($http) {
        this.pageTitle = "NP04 Cryostat"
        this.natalie = 1;
        $http.get("cryostat.conn.php")
           .then(function (response) {this.TT0101 = response.data.records;});
    }
});
```

Comment: what are you populating with multiple requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understood that component can treat only one http request

This is not at all true. Where did you hear that? It is easy to make two requests simultaneously with `$q.all()`:

```
var promiseOne = $http.get("query1.php");
var promiseTwo = $http.get("query2.php");

$q.all([promiseOne, promiseTwo]).then(function(resultArray) {
  $scope.resultOne = resultArray[0];
  $scope.resultTwo = resultArray[1];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this, but I'm getting following suggestion in IDE on $q.all: Missing import statement and required() missing

Comment: I made a typo in my code. Call to `.then()` needs the `function` keyword. Also, you will need to inject the `$q` dependency in the same way that you inject `$http`

Comment: that's what I thought. thanks! but now when running the page, I'm getting "[$http:badreq] Http request configuration must be an object.  Received: cryostat.conn.php" in the browser DevTools. May this be due to the fact that I don't have server installed and PHP code is not executed?

Comment: The string parameter is supposed to be a full URL when calling `$http.get`. This is a contrived example. But how to use `$http` has already been answered elsewhere

Comment: what to do if I'm not using $scope but controller?

Comment: so I tried and it reads correctly, but now I can't display this on my page, I used cryostatController.TT0101 instead of this.TT0101

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `$q.all()` for your purpose.

```
var myData_One, myData_two;
var promises = [];
function promiseA() {
    let deferred = $q.defer();

    ajaxCall().then((response) => {
        $scope.myData_One = response;
        deferred.resolve();
    }, (error) => {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
function promiseB() {
    let deferred = $q.defer();

    ajaxCall().then((response) => {
        $scope.myData_two = response;
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }, (error) => {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
var promises = [promiseA(), promiseB()];
$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    //Do whatever you wish to with response data from both promises.
});
```